# Access: Getting Value From List Box

Tags: excel, ms-access, insert, vba

I'm trying to get a value from a ListBox, `List80`. I'm trying to grab the options chosen, say `Red`, `Blue`, `Yellow`, and have it inserted into a table using a query. I have written the following query:

```
INSERT INTO Test_User_Activity
VALUES (5554, 4, "Something", Forms![Activities]![List80]);
```

It runs, but doesn't return any items that were selected in the List. I did something similar to this with a multi-select dropdown list and am wondering where i'm going wrong.

Comment: @HansUp Not sure if it matters but I did Msgbox instead of Debug and its returning Null

Comment: @hansup the only column i have displayed for the user to choose from. The bound column is at "1"

Comment: @HansUP It's Simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access a value of a combo box or list box please use SelectedValue in VBA, i.e. Forms("Activities").Controls("List80").SelectedValue or you can access the value by first determining the SelectedIndex and then pick the value. Then you can use this value in a query.

Comment: Is there any other way to do this so I can access the values from a simple query instead of writing out some VBA code?

Comment: May be it's worth trying because Debug.Print Forms![Activities]![List80] does not work.